# Task is to "stringify" a value in Python. If the value is a dict obj which has nested dicts, the function must recursively call itself for the nested

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, stringify

My task is to write a function in Python, which would work similarly as JS's JSON.stringify() method. The func's signature is - `stringify(value[, replacer[, spaces_count]])`. So if `value` is a dict with nested dicts, it must call the implemented function recursively for the nested dict. For example the value is:
`data = { "hello": "world", "is": True, "nested": { "count": 5 } }`
Then the result must be:

```
{
  hello: world
  is: True
  nested: {
  count: 5
  }
}
```

So I wrote a code:

```
PRIMITIVES = [str, float, int, bool]
PLAINS = [list, tuple, set]


def stringify(value, replacer: str = ' ', spaces_count: int = 1) -> str:
    
    if type(value) in PRIMITIVES:
        return str(value)
    
    elif type(value) in PLAINS:
        return str(value)
    
    else:
        result = list()
        opening_bracket = '{'
        closing_bracket = '}'
        indent = replacer * spaces_count
        result.append(opening_bracket)
        keys = sorted(set(value))
        for key in keys:
            if type(value[key]) in PRIMITIVES or type(value[key]) in PLAINS:
                result.append(f'{indent + str(key)}: {str(value[key])}')
            else:
                
                stringify(value[key])
                result.append(f'{indent + str(key)}: {str(value[key])}')
        result.append(closing_bracket)
        resulting_string = '\n'.join(result)
        return resulting_string
```

And with it I get the following result:

```
{
 hello: world        
 is: True
 nested: {'count': 5}
}
```

P.S. with non-dictionary values the function must just return `str(value)`

Answer (score 0):

> *with non-dictionary values the function must just return `str(value)`*

then why are you checking against *`PRIMITIVES`* and *`PLAINS`*? You should be able to get your desired output<sup>([view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEX4H.png))</sup> with just

```py
def stringify(value, replacer:str=' ', spaces_count:int=1) -> str:
    if not isinstance(value, dict): return str(value) # return repr(value) # 
    curIndent, braceIndent = replacer*spaces_count, replacer*(spaces_count-1)
    unbraced = '\n'.join([ # ',\n'.join([ #
        # f'{curIndent}{repr(k)}: {stringify(v, replacer, spaces_count+1).strip()}' 
        f'{curIndent}{k}: {stringify(v, replacer, spaces_count+1).strip()}' 
        for k, v in value.items()
    ])
    return braceIndent + '{\n' + unbraced + '\n' + braceIndent + '}'

dStr = stringify({ "hello": "world", "is": True, "nested": { "count": 5 } })
```

although, if you use [`repr(value)`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/repr)/`{repr(k)}`/`',\n'.join` (see the commented bits of code) instead of *`str(value)`*/*`{k}`*/*`'\n'.join`* [respectively], then

- [`dStr`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvbHP.png) could be parsed<sup>([view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWBoV.png))</sup> with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) (or even just [`eval`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval) but that's less safe), and also
- stringified objects with multiline strings wouldn't break

  - for example, see the stringified representation with and without `repr` for <kbd>`{'header': 'some header', 'content': 'para 1\npara 2'}`</kbd> :

    | without `repr` | with `repr` |
    | --- | --- |
    | [image: wo] | [image: with repr] |